# Numeric Citation with Biblatex does not work?

Tags: latex, citations, biblatex

I am trying to cite with the numeric style in latex, but that doesn't work for me. I referenced the biblatex Package in the following way:

```
'\usepackage[
'backend=biber, 
'style = numeric-comp,
'citestyle=numeric-comp,%numeric, 
'%  bibstyle=ieee,
'%  doi=false,
'%  isbn=false,
'url=false]{biblatex}           
'%\addbibresource{refs} 
'\bibliography{refs}
```

and cited in the following way:

> Text... \cite{Copil.2016}

And the citation result is:

> Text... [Copil.2016]

I Would lkike to have the Citation as follows:

> Text... [1]

Does anybody know the solution for my problem?

Comment: I found the solution:

Comment: My Texstudio had still the configuration that it runs with bibtex instead of biblatex; so if anyone has the same mistake: options - configuration - run with biber

Answer (score 3):

As you have already mentioned yourself, you have to configure your Tex editor (e.g. TeXstudio) to use biber.

You can do that by going to

```
Options > Configure TeXstudio > Build > Default Bibliography > Biber
```

Then you have to configure the command in options if it isn't set by default.

```
Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands > Biber > Choose file > (in Debian) /usr/bin/biber
```

For more information, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102803/texstudio-how-to-automate-latex-biber-sequence-of-compilation).